# How to cut/split multipolygon with blade (linestring) into two pieces using PostGIS?

Tags: postgis, postgresql, sql, query, splitting

I struggle to do split operation in postgis I tried to build a query but Im always fail.

Id like to cut a multipoligon with a blade (a linestring) into two pieces. These two objects have specific SRID of my country.

query:

```
CREATE TABLE Cut_result AS
SELECT ST_SPLIT(poligon,blade)
FROM (SELECT
ST_MakeLine(700264 126376, 780844 122481)::geometry(LINESTRING,23700) AS blade),
SELECT FROM county AS poligon;
```

ERROR

```
ERROR:  syntax error at or near "126376"
LINE 5: ST_MakeLine(700264 126376, 780844 122481)::geometry(LINESTRI...
                           ^
********** Error **********
```

Comment: It looks like you are mixing a table (`county` / `poligon`) and the geometry, but its hard to tell - perhaps you could tell us what happens instead of "Im always fail"? That is, we know it doesn't work, but an error message might help more. Also, what is the schema for `county`, and what do you expect `Cut_result` to look like?

Comment: So I have a multipoligon called County which I want to cut into two pieces with a line called Blade.

Comment: What table is the `county` multipolygon stored in? What do you want `Cut-Result` to look like?

Comment: County is a table with geom and other columns. It is a multipoligon

Comment: Last time you said the geometry was called `County`. Now you say the table is called `County`. A table is not a geometry. Please edit the question to show the schema for the table you have (not a screenshot of some geometry), and tell us what the output table (`Cut_result`) should look like. Just post the SQL. Last chance.

Comment: Im not a native speaker of english Im sorry for that. So I would like to execute this operation shown above the picture. Blue line is the blade, and county is a brown polygon.

Comment: I would like to cut into two pieces along the blue line

Comment: @BradHards plz help me

Comment: I can't help you - there is no way to tell what the right commands would be unless you can tell me what the input data schema is. Sorry.

Comment: what do you mean data schema? I have a table called Country. It has a geom column and other non question related insignificant columns. And I want to cut into two pieces with a line. and a result will be a geometry collection with two multipoligons

Comment: As a suggestion you could edit your Question to include the SQL to (1) create a test "county" which is a rectangle, (2) create a test line that extends outside the rectangle at both ends, and (3) your attempt at splitting the former by the latter to create two new geometries.

Comment: http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.3/interactive/app-psql.html and look for \d+ command. Show us the output of that command applied to the County (or Country, whatever you really called it) table.

Comment: Just a guess, I'm assuming he is trying to do:  ```CREATE TABLE Cut_result AS
SELECT ST_SPLIT(poligon.geom,blade.geom)
FROM (SELECT
ST_GeomFromText('LINESTRING(700264 126376, 780844 122481)',23700) AS geom) As blade,
SELECT geom FROM county AS poligon;```

Answer (score 4):

The error you are seeing is because ST_MakeLine does not accept WKT style arguments. There are [multiple usage options](http://postgis.refractions.net/documentation/manual-2.0/ST_MakeLine.html), but for you, probably something like:

```
ST_MakeLine(ST_MakePoint(700264, 126376, 23700), ST_MakePoint(780844, 122481, 23700))
```

will be best.

That may not fix the real problem (in that you aren't specifying the table that `County` multipolygon should be selected from), but since you didn't tell us that, we should make that a separate question if you need more help.